# How do I use the emulator with AppInventor?

Tags: android-emulator

How did you enable an emulator for AppInventor? I want to test out the junk that I created on a emulator, before using it on my phone.

Answer (score 2):

[Check out this page](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/setup-emulator.html) on the App Inventor website on how to use App Inventor with an emulator.